# How can i write to especific line on a text file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello im having struggle finding a way to write text to a especific line in python3.
Can somebody helpme ?
Example:
I have a text file with 100 lines I want to write to line 25 for example.

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    lines = open(file_name, 'r+')
    linhas = lines.readlines()
    linhas[line_num] = text
    out = open(file_name, 'w')
    out.writelines(lines)
    out.close()
```

I have tried this code but it returns 0 in the variable linhas

Comment: Post more details

Comment: Ok like what details ?

Comment: Like what you want to print, what have you tried so far etc etc everything that would be helpful to understand what you're looking for

Comment: This code seems like it should work (hard to test without a [mre]). Can you be more clear on what is not working?

Comment: It is in another part of the code the error thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will have to read the complete file, line by line, update the required line and write the file, Here is the code for it,

```
# with is like your try .. finally block in this case
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
    # read a list of lines into data
    data = file.readlines()

print data

# now change the 25th line, note that you have to add a newline
data[24] = 'The new text to be written\n'

# and write everything back
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines( data )
```

Comment: I got "list assignment index out of range" in data[24]

Comment: Maybe your file in not having so many lines, please check the length of data, I am assuming that the file has 100 lines and I am trying to change the 25th line

Comment: that's correct the file has 100 lines if I put 4 in data says the same

Comment: What is the length of data? Can you print len(data) and check, it should be 100

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, can you check if data is an array of lines in your file?

Comment: Yes it is a list I used type() it says it's a list.

Comment: Never mind I think is a error on another part of the code but thanks your code works !!